# In MongoDB is $set faster than $addToSet $each?

Tags: java, json, database, mongodb

I've got a MongoDB document that has an array of Strings (see document below). This set of strings is matched perfectly with a Set in local memory of my program. When updating the MongoDB document, would it be faster to just replace the existing data with `$set` using the local memory `Set<String>` object or is it better to use `$addToSet` `$each` for each String in the `Set<String>` object?

```
{
  "disabled_commands": [
    "resume",
    "play",
    "ping"
  ],
}
```

Comment: If you have the set already available in memory then run a simple `$set`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Robo 3T](https://robomongo.org/download) , it is a free open source MONGODB GUI. You can create a dummy collection and documents in it and use your mongo db commands, it will show the result finding speed.